# how to achieve mutual exclusion using synchronized method in this application

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, mutual-exclusion

i have run into a little problem in here. I am doing a concurrent program in Java. Problem is: There are 4 people (students) that are trying to access printer, to print 5 documents. But only one can print at the time (kind of obvious) 5 documents. When they finish they notify other that they done and other thread accesses the resource. i have a Main class, student class and Monitor (laser printer), Document class that holds info about the document like (number of pages, name user id etc)+ few interfaces for printer. I have managed to run successfully threads but they are not synchronized (mutual exclusion)
So the question is how do i achieve mutual exclusion ( that only one person can print at the time his number of docs)
Thank you for looking, time and hints :)

Main class

```
    String S1Name = "bob";
    String S2Name = "klara";
    String S3Name = "John";
    String S4Name = "Iga";

    String T1Name = "Man";
    String T2Name = "Woman";


    final int NoOfDocs = 5;
    ServicePrinter sp = new LaserPrinter();

    ThreadGroup groupA = new ThreadGroup("Group A"); 
    ThreadGroup groupB = new ThreadGroup("Group B");

    Student student1 = new Student(sp,NoOfDocs,S1Name, groupA);
    Student student2 = new Student(sp,NoOfDocs,S2Name, groupA);
    Student student3 = new Student(sp,NoOfDocs,S3Name, groupA);
    Student student4 = new Student(sp,NoOfDocs,S4Name, groupA);

    TonerTechnician TT = new TonerTechnician(groupB);
    PaperTechnician PT = new PaperTechnician(groupB);

    /*
     * Start Student Threads
     */
    student1.start();
    student2.start();
    student3.start();
    student4.start();

    /*
     * Start Technician threads
     */
    TT.start();
    PT.start();
```

Student Class

```
 private final ServicePrinter serviceprinter;
    private final int NoOfDocs;
    private final String Name;
    private final ThreadGroup threadgroup;

    public Student(ServicePrinter serviceprinter, int NoOfDocs, String Name, ThreadGroup threadgroup)
    {
        this.serviceprinter = serviceprinter;
        this.NoOfDocs = NoOfDocs; 
        this.Name = Name;
        this.threadgroup = threadgroup;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        /*
         * each students prints 5 documents (different name and length)
         */
        final LaserPrinter lp = new LaserPrinter();
        //sleep from 1 to 5 sec random time
        final Random random = new Random();       
        char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        /*
         * Create random document name 10 characters long
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
            sb.append(c);
        }
        String docName  = sb.toString();
        /*
         * print 5 documents (random sleep time between printing)
         */
        for(int i = 0; i < NoOfDocs; i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                Document coursework = new Document(Name,docName,random.nextInt(90)+10);
                lp.printDocument(coursework);
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000)+4000);                
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }            
        }
        System.out.println("User: " + Name+ " completed printing");
```

Monitor class

```
    int tonerLevel = 500;
    int paperLevel = 250;

    private final String PrinterName = "HP";
    private final String PrinterID = "LX-440";
    private int CurrentPaperLevel;
    private int CurrentTonerLevel;
    private int NoOfDocsPrinted;

    @Override
    public synchronized void printDocument(Document document) {
        System.out.println(document);

    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Keppil sorry forgot to actually ask the questions. Post updated

Comment: Well it seems your monitor class extends another class. Is printDocument synchronized in the superclass as well? Also why are you creating a new printer object in run instead of using the one you pass to the Student class?

Comment: At Student class you are using a local `LaserPrinter` instead of using the shared object `serviceprinter`. If you change that, base on that `printDocument` of `ServicePrinter` is synchronized I think it might work.

Comment: You have 5 printers which can be used at the same time. (`final LaserPrinter lp = new LaserPrinter();` in your run method)

Comment: @AliAlamiri printDocument is a method in Interface Printer (not synchronized). the reason why i create new object is because threads need to communicate data through the shared laserprinter object

Comment: @assylias i dont have 5 printers that can be used. i am printing 5 documents

Comment: But have you tried using the shared printer? and why are you not declaring the method as synchronized in the interface but implementing it as synchronized?

Comment: @JoseRenato serviceprinter is a interface that technicians will use later on. This one does not apply to Student class

Comment: @MaciejCygan ok. But considering that `printDocument` is synchronized, if you use a shared instance of `LaserPrinter`, it will be guaranteed that the printing of a document is atomic.

Comment: @JoseRenato I am kinda lost, where should i use the laserprinter instance ?

Comment: @MaciejCygan still you create 4 printers in your code, one per student.

Comment: @assylias i just removed the code in question, but still getting the same result. In fact this code did not make any difference

Comment: @MaciejCygan you should create a `LaserPrinter` instance at some point of the program, like the main class, and pass it through the instances of `Student` and `TonerTechnician`, so that the synchronized operations, like `printDocument`, can be done by only one user at time. Got it?

Comment: @JoseRenato yup got it now, it seems to all work :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple mutex implementation but you should use java.util.concurrent package for synchronization

EDIT: Changed mutex to semaphore (it makes more sense)

A simple mutex implementaion:

```
public class Mutex {

    private int semaphore;

    public synchronized void aquire() throws InterruptedException {

        if(semaphore < 0) {
            wait();
        }

        semaphore--;

    }

    public synchronized void release() {

        if(semaphore < 0) {
            semaphore++;
            notify();            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the mutex field in your class? Object.wait() and Object.notify() should be all you need to create a mutex.

Comment: @creechy - how else would you aquire a lock for the first time. Each thread would be blocked when he calls aquire()

Comment: Oh right I see. I generally use wait() and notify() directly, kind of threw me off. Like just creating an object and then use syncronized (object) { } for mutual exclusion.

Comment: it all makes sense having two methods (acquiring and releasing) but when i have one method for printing. How do i acquire and release in one method ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're creating a local printer object in your run method instead of using the shared one you pass to the `Student` class. Try using the shared printer that you pass and see what you get. Also we need to see how you use `printDocument` in `ServicePrinter`. This is because you are using a `ServicePrinter` object in your `Student` class, and the implementation of `printDocument` in `ServicePrinter` may not be correct (that is if you actually have it implemented in the superclass)